# How to leverage the *C* in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c, api

I've been doing iPhone development full-time over the last couple of months.

*Having previous experience only in OOP*, I've relied heavily on Apple's APIs, which eventhough majestic I must reckon, led me to write code that in retrospective looks *like a weird mix of ruby/smalltalk with added boilerplate*.

So I'm thinking I'm missing out, and  ordering K&R. Yet I wonder how what I'll learn, can specifically be put to good use in iOS work, without fighting against the devices' API and the whole OO pardadigm ?

Comment: K&R is not going to help you learn OO.

Comment: @Jason whether you missed the point or I made quite a bad case.

Comment: Well, Objective C isn't that far from Smalltalk.

Comment: Why not post some snippets to SO with the question "is this idiomatic ObjC" or "am I writing too much boilerplate here"? I don't know ObjC btw, but judging from how different C and C++ are, I doubt that learning C is going to instantly improve your ObjC skills.

Comment: Perhaps a little bit of both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C is a superset of C. You can intermingle Objective-C and C function calls, statements, etc.

So for example, if you prefer Posix sockets to NSSocketPort, you can just mix in the C socket functions wherever you want. Or, if you wanted to keep it a little more object oriented, you could wrap C statements in an Objective-C function call that would isolate your C code from the rest of your Objective-C code.

Comment: With this question I was actually wondering about how to use purely C constructs in a way that would not conflict with Apple's message passing APIs. It seems I should be taking baby steps at first, so this is a decent answer.

Answer (score 3):

The lower level APIs are largley in straight C, perhaps you'd like to explore them? For example [Quartz 2D](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) has a C API.

Comment: But most of the C APIs in iOS / OS X are pseudo-objective-oriented. If it weren't for the need to make Carbon C API to placate the old timers, Apple/NeXT would have preferred to create Objective-C APIs only.

Answer (score 0):

Something that might help you understand the relationship between C and Objective-C would be to create an Objective-C wrapper for some C code. I’d recommend writing a simple iPhone app scripted in Lua. That should be enough of a project to really look at the C.

Answer (score 0):

Not learning C is not missing out on anything.

Answer (score 0):

I almost agree with @jeff except that I don't see why so many beginning Objective C programmers go straight for the iPhone stuff when they could be running a Mac app with much less hassle and convert it later.

But yes, buying a copy of K&R would be a very good idea (as well as getting a copy of the C90 or C99 standards, if you can afford them). In fact, I have a book on iOS games that suggests going straight to vanilla C for a lot of the low-level stuff to cut out the messaging overhead for performance's sake. Essentially, you're not doing anything you're not "supposed" to do by using C functions; the C library is still there to be used, so you aren't doing anything particularly strange or kludgy.